# Unable to initialize when loading Firebase SDKs from reserved URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, create-react-app

I'm trying to use reserved URLs of firebase in my create-react-app, and following instructions provided in firebase site. I've included SDKs (app, firestore, analytics) and then added the `<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>` entry after SDKs inclusion for initializing the SDKs.
My body tag of index.html (unbuilt) looks like this:

```
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->

    <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.22.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.22.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

    <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.22.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.22.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <!-- Load the Firebase SDKs before loading this file -->
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
```

My firebase.js page looks like this:

```
    import firebase from "firebase/app";
    import "firebase/auth";
    import "firebase/firestore";
    import { createFirestoreInstance } from "redux-firestore";
    
    const getRrfProps = (reduxStore) => {
      // initialize firebase and firestore
      console.log("inside firebase.js");
      // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
      try {
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
          /*  console.log(
            "inside dev env apps.length if block, apikey: ",
            process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APIKEY
          ); */
          if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
            const firebaseConfig = {
              apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APIKEY,
              authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
              databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASEURL,
              projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
              storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
              messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
              appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID,
              measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID,
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
          } else throw new Error("Firebase Config Error ");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          "[FIREBASE] Firebase not configured or initialized : ",
          error
        );
        return undefined;
      }
    
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .enablePersistence()
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.code === "failed-precondition") {
            console.error(
              "[FIREBASE PERSISTENCE (CACHE)] - Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled in one tab at a a time."
            );
          } else if (err.code === "unimplemented") {
            console.error(
              "[FIREBASE PERSISTENCE (CACHE)] - The current browser does not support all of the features required to enable persistence"
            );
          }
        });
...
... other codes ...
...
..
```

I know that importing the firebase libraries again is redundant but it is needed for my dev environment. In production environment, the SDKs seem to be injecting since there is a warning thrown in my dev environment of loading firebase twice. But the initializing of firebase is not happening since it is going to the throw statement and an exception is generated. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't mix script includes with imports from module bundlers.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) makes it pretty clear that you have to choose one or the other - they have different integration paths.  If you're using a bundler with imports, don't use the scripts includes at all.

Comment: I've already mentioned why I have used both. the module bundles are for the dev environment, the script is for prod. Are you suggesting that is the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Yes, I can only imagine that will cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was in the firebase.json file which is the hosting configuration file. I removed these two aspects and it started working:

```
"rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
```

&

```
"headers": [
      {
        "source": "/service-worker.js",
        "headers": [{ "key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache" }]
      }
    ],
```